# Is mysqli extension ubiquitous since PHP 5.3?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, php-7

We have developed a web-application that runs on various server environments (> PHP 5.3), which currently uses the "deprecated" **mysql** extension to connect to mysql. Since PHP 7 however, it seems mysql is not installed by default, only the newer **mysqli** extension.

So we would like to convert our scripts to use mysqli, but we are concerned if the mysqli extension is not installed on "older" servers. So the question basically goes: Is mysqli generally ubiquitous since PHP version 5.3? Does anyone know from what version of PHP mysqli comes installed as default?

If some of our users are on hosts without mysqli, we would need to create a wrapper script, that detects if mysqli is available, and fall back to mysql if not.

Anyone with knowledge care to shine some light on this? Thanks

Comment: MySQLi was included with PHP from version 5.0 and forward. I've added a simple script to detect if MySQLi is installed. If you need help using this condition to adapt between mysql/mysqli let me know and I will add to my answer.

Comment: By the way, at least on Ubuntu, MySQLi is packaged together with the other MySQL extensions. So if `mysql_` is available, `mysqli_` will be too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQLi was added with PHP 5.0

You can check if `mysqli` is installed by doing this:

```
if ( function_exists('mysqli_connect') ) 
    // mysqli is installed
```

Comment: Thanks. Does that mean that mysqli is *almost* certainly installed on all PHP servers from 5.0 and up? I'd prefer not to use detection, as that would mean we would need to build a wrapper for both mysql and mysqli.

Comment: Yes, mysqli is installed by default on all PHP versions starting with 5.0 - you also would not need more than one wrapper assuming you've structured a database object to accept both mysql and mysqli. If you need help with a sample DB class that can accept both let me know and I'll update my answer.